# ANTLR4 change listener during parse

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have an ANTLR4 listener which handles a standard and well-formed grammar, however am struggling with how to deal the non-standard implementations.  Although all of the variants go through the lexer without problems the parse stage is a lot trickier.

A traditional way of doing this would be something like

```
// Header of document
variant = STANDARD;
if (header.indexOf("microsoft") != -1) {
  variant = MICROSOFT;
} else if (header.indexOf("google") != -1) {
  variant = GOOGLE;
}

...

// Parsing a particular element
if (variant.equals(MICROSOFT)) {
  // Microsoft-specific stuff
} else if (variant.equals(GOOGLE)) {
  // Google-specific stuff
} else {
  // Standard stuff
}
```

but this quickly becomes unmaintainable.  The obvious solution is to have a `ParseTreeListener` for the standard implementation and then subclass it for each variant, but I don't know which variant it is until I've started the parse.

So how can I either switch from one listener to another part-way through the parse, or restart the parse with a new listener once I know which variant I'm dealing with?

Answer (score 2):

If these variants occur frequently, you might want to consider embedding custom code to handle context sensitive parsing by using predicates (the `{...}?` construct in the following pseudo grammar):

```
rule
 : { boolean-expression-a }? a-alternative
 | { boolean-expression-b }? b-alternative
 | /* fall through */        not-a-or-b-alternative
 ;
```

Let's say you want to parse a file containing `chunk`s. A `chunk` consists of a `header` and a `data` row. In the `header` you can set your variant. The `data` of a normal variant contains 3 `NUMBER`s, Google's variant contains 2 `NUMBER`s and Microsoft's variant contains a single `NUMBER`. An example of such a file would look like this:

```
header: none
data: 1 2 3 
header: google
data: 4 5
header: microsoft
data: 6
```

And here's a demo of a context sensitive ANTLR v4 grammar able to parse this:

```
grammar T;

@parser::members {

  enum Variant { 

    GOOGLE, 
    MICROSOFT, 
    OTHER; 

    public static Variant tryValueOf(String name) {
      try {
        return Variant.valueOf(name.toUpperCase());
      }
      catch(Exception e) {
        return OTHER;
      }
    }
  } 

  private Variant variant = Variant.OTHER;
}

parse
 : chunk+ EOF
 ;

chunk
 : header data
 ;

header
 : K_HEADER COLON NAME {variant = Variant.tryValueOf($NAME.text);}
 ;

data
 : {variant == Variant.MICROSOFT}? K_DATA COLON NUMBER               #MicrosoftData
 | {variant == Variant.GOOGLE}?    K_DATA COLON NUMBER NUMBER        #GoogleData
 |                                 K_DATA COLON NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER #OtherData
 ;

K_DATA   : 'data';
K_HEADER : 'header';
NAME     : [a-zA-Z]+;
NUMBER   : [0-9]+;
COLON    : ':';
SPACE    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Resulting in the following parse:

[image]

Comment: This feels to me like it's the same if/then/else mess as I have in the Java, just pushed down a level.  I was hoping for some way of resetting the listener and restarting the parse (as I should know about the variant very early on in the parse).

Comment: @jgm I don't know exactly how you implemented it in Java, but I thought the inline ANTLR predicates would be more succinct, and would result in a parse tree reflecting your variants. I've not looked into resetting listeners and or visitors, but will have a look later on and update the answer when I find something.